# Software for watching TV

Tags: windows-7, usb, media-player, tuner-card

So, I just got a new [ENUTV-2](http://www.encore-usa.com/product_item.php?region=us&bid=2&pgid=17&pid=375#DOWNLOAD) USB TV Tuner Box, and it works fine overall. The driver seems to be OK, but the utility provided by encore doesn't seem to be working 100% in win 7. The only real issue is that I can't mute it, or change the volume level. So I'd like to know:
**Is there good (free) software out there for watching TV with a tuner?**

EDIT: Windows media center doesn't work. I have it in my version of windows, but it claims to have no support for my region (Brazil). I'm under the impression that the only regional issue is the lack of support for downloading time-tables and stuff, which is something I really don't care about. The drivers for my tuner are installed, why can't WMC just see that the tuner is ON and capture the stream coming from it?

Thanks

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried (version of Windows depending) Media Center?

It is free and comes with Windows Home Premium and above!

Comment: Just tried it, and it says it doesn't support TV tuning for my country (Brazil). Which is strange, given that the Tuner Box is suppose to do the tunning.

Comment: Looking into it, WMC says the same thing if I select my country as USA. So it probably doesn't support my tuner.

Comment: Go figure... I selected Bosnia as my country and that seemed to work. WMC allowed me to go through with the configuration. And now the "Live TV" option shows up in the main menu, as it should. But clicking on it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

That's because of your gpu drivers. I had the same problem updated them, and it worked just fine. I have an nvidia 9500 gt with 196. something drivers.